# Sorting on one field, then another but still keeping null last

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_l.entries 
WHERE bindningstid = 1 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN rabatt IS NULL THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END, rabatt DESC, 
    CASE 
        WHEN paslag IS NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END, paslag ASC
```

So I first have a value (rabatt) which I want to order desc, then I want to order the field paslag Asc but still keep null last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace cases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM forum_l.entries 
WHERE bindningstid = 1 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN rabatt IS NULL THEN 0
       ELSE 1 
    END, rabatt DESC, 
    CASE 
        WHEN paslag IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END, paslag ASC
```